# Simple way to create Hazelcast cluster on Multi-hosts Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, hazelcast

I have only a short time to work with Docker so i'm not very clear about docker networking. Currently I'm trying to convert a system to use docker for deployment. The system contains multiple Java application servers: API server, Chat server, Web Workbench, Plugin Server...

I already created docker-compose file and other Dockerfiles for each server also. This is the a part of docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  apiserver:
    build:
      context: ./apiserver
      dockerfile: APIServerDockerfile
  image: apiserver
  container_name: apiserver
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  tty: true
  depends_on:
    - mariadb
  networks:
    - chat_net

chatserver:
  build:
    context: ./chatserver
    dockerfile: ChatserverDockerfile
  image: chatserver
  container_name: chatserver
  ports:
    - "8088:8088"
  tty: true
  depends_on:
    - mariadb
  networks:
    - chat_net

mariadb:
  image: mariadb/server:10.3
  environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abc12345
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  networks:
    - chat_net
  restart: always
  container_name: mariadb10.3
  volumes:
    - ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  chat_net:
  external: true
```

chat_net is a bridge network as default. The system needs to be distributed, which means apiserver and chatserver and others can be installed on different physical servers. Apiserver and chatserver shares hazelcast cluster to communicate. Normally each server has a hazelcast.xml with some information like this:

```
<group>
  <name>CHAT_NET_OVERALL_V2</name>
  <password>abc123!@#</password>
</group>

<network>
   <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">8701</port>
   <join>
     <multicast enabled="false"></multicast>
     <tcp-ip enabled="true">
          <member>127.0.0.1</member>
          <member>15.23.24.56</member>
     </tcp-ip>
   </join>
</network>
```

Hazelcast cluster connects using ICP/IP with server addresses. Now using docker hazelcast cluster not created using bridge network. If I use network_mode:host, they can form cluster, but our case requires multi-hosts so it's not a solution. In my understanding, I need an overlay network. What i tried to do is to create an overlay network, but even if I add IP of servers in overlay network, the hazelcast cluster cannot be created, each server starts their standalone hazelcast.

So anyone please tells me which is the simplest way to create hazelcast cluster in multi-hosts enviroment? I knew there is some other services like Swarm or Kubernetes or Weavenet but not sure which one could be the best fit for my case. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topic is explained in the following article: [Configuring Hazelcast in Non-Orchestrated Docker Environments](https://hazelcast.com/blog/configuring-hazelcast-in-non-orchestrated-docker-environments/)

Basically, without third-party tooling you have two options:

- either use the network mode `host` in Docker
- or combine Docker port mapping (`-p 5701:5701`) with defining public (external) address in Hazelcast configuration (`-Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=$DOCKER_HOST_IP:$DOCKER_HOST_PORT`)

Comment: I tried to use network_mode: host. This way makes hazelcast cluster can be formed but it's not very convenient for other aspects. For example if I develop in my Mac OS computer, this mode prevents me from connecting to MariaDB on container, and I cannot access Swagger UI on API/Chat server using localhost:port anymore. So can u explain more details about your second option? I'm not very clear about it, this is using bridge or overlay network?

Comment: Did you look into the blog article?
The second way uses the `bridge` mode. You have to make sure the member reports the correct address to other members. In multihost environments you have to use the address of the Docker host. It's configurable by system property `hazelcast.local.publicAddress` as decribed in the documentation.

The overlay mode is a little bit simpler as you don't need to map port. You still need to make sure the Hazelcast uses the correct interface (IP address)  to report it to other members.

Comment: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.1/manual/html-single/index.html#system-properties

Comment: Thank u very much for your support. I have only 1 case: our host has internal IP address,  i exposed 2 services (both on that host) using hazelcast as 8701->8701, 8702->8701. Set hazelcast.local.publicAddress = Host's Internal IP for both docker containers, set member list of hazelcast for both 2 services as: IP:8701, IP:8702, using TCP-IP. But hazelcast said socketException unreachable for both. Does this means we need to use Public IP Address for docker's host? Normally we use multi-hosts but sometimes we need to support multi-services on 1 server thanks to lacking resources.

Comment: If you change the port, you have to list it also in the tcp-ip discovery for members. E.g. <member>15.23.24.56:8701</member>